# Pass the ArrayList got error and String Array works fine in PagerAdapter?

Tags: android, android-pageradapter

I am calling a Pager Adapter from my Activity. I am getting the data from the JSON and passing into the ArrayList  **mSlidedata**

```
ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(mContext, mSlideData);
slideShowPager.setAdapter(adapter);
slideShowPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

ImagePagerAdapter is the class where I extends the PagerAdapter. Here is the code:

```
public class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
private ArrayList<SlideData> slideShowImages;

public ImagePagerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SlideData> mSlideShowData) {
    mContext = context;
    slideShowImages = mSlideShowData;
    mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mContext);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return slideShowImages.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((ImageView) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    ImageView imageViewSlideShow = new ImageView(mContext);
    int padding = mContext.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
    imageViewSlideShow.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
    imageViewSlideShow.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
    mImageLoader.DisplayImage(ServiceURLs.URL+slideShowImages.get(position).photo_name, R.drawable.loading, imageViewSlideShow);
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageViewSlideShow, 0);
    return imageViewSlideShow;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object); 
    }
 }
```

here is all code what I use to implement for the PagerAdapter

**Problem:** When activity start Ist time run Fine but when I back and reload the Activity again error

**LogCat Detail**:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The application's PagerAdapter changed the adapter's contents without calling PagerAdapter#notifyDataSetChanged!

Expected adapter item count: 10, found: 0 Pager id: com.akm.demo.activities:id/slideShowPager Pager class: class android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
```

**Alternative Solution** : Passing the ArrayList into the String Array

```
 for (int i = 0; i < mSlideData.size(); i++)
 {
     slideImagesArray[i] = ServiceURLs.URL+mSlideData.get(i).photo_name;
 }  
 adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter(mContext, imagesStringArray);
 slideShowPager.setAdapter(adapter);
 slideShowPager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

Works fine no problem occur from String Array.

So, Why problem happen during the **ArrayList** and **String Array** works fine **??**

Comment: try to paste the log file

Comment: I have mention the error  what I got in the logcat @Kalai.G

Comment: I added the LogCat @Kalai.G